# Soundcloud Live Comment Stream

Tags: api, comments, streaming, live, soundcloud

I am working on an app and would like to display all the comments for a given Soundcloud track  in real time. We have created a custom html5 audio player and it is not the format of the standard embedabble soundcloud player. The comments should show up in a given space and follow the progress of the song. It would display the comment with a timestamp of "5 seconds" when the song has played for 5 seconds, etc.

Currently we have only found that you must make a separate API call for each new comment.

Answer (score 0):

The custom player from SoundCloud doesn't support this at the moment.

But if you're building a player using the SC.stream function of the SoundCloud JS SDK you can use the ontimedcomments options:

SC.stream("/tracks", {
  autoPlay: true,
  ontimedcomments: function(comments){
    console.log("First Comment at this timestamp", comments[0].body);
  }
});

The only downside with this is that you have to build the player UI yourself.
There are some more examples in this post: http://developers.soundcloud.com/blog/rich-media-using-timed-comments